# Efficient way of applying specific function to structured column in Spark data frame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have data in a Spark data frame, with a column `col` that contains *structured data* of the form:

```
------ col -------   # Column whose elements are structures
field0  field1 …     # StructType with StructFields (variable names and count)
[1,2,3] [4,5]  [6]   # Each field is of type ArrayType
[1,2]   [3]    []
…
```

where *the number and the names of the fields are not fixed*.

**What is the most efficient way of calculating the total number of elements in each row?** In the above example, the expected resulting data frame would thus be:

```
num_elements
6
3
…
```

There is always the solution of a user defined function:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def num_elements(all_arrays_in_row):
    return sum(map(len, all_arrays_in_row))
num_elements = pyspark.sql.functions.udf(num_elements, IntegerType())

data_frame.select(num_elements(data_frame.col)).show()  # Number of elements in each row
```

Now, I am not sure whether this is generally efficient, because:

1. Function `num_elements()` is in Python.
2. If the fields happen to not be stored together for some reason, the `map()` forces a fetch of each array before calculating their length.

More generally, a "pure" Spark approach would be more efficient, but it is eluding me. What I tried so far is the following, but this is way more cumbersome than the approach above, and is also not complete:

1. Get the field names `field0`, etc. with `[field.name for field in data_frame.select("col").schema.fields[0].dataType.fields]` (cumbersome).
2. For each field name, efficiently calculate the size of its array:

   ```
   sizes_one_field = data_frame.select(pyspark.sql.functions.size(
                                       data_frame.col.getField(field_name))
   ```

Now, I am stuck at this point because I am not sure how to sum together the 1-column data frames `sizes_one_field` (there is one for each field name). Plus, maybe there is a way of directly applying the `size()` function to each field of column `col` in Spark (through some kind of map?)? Or some completely different approach to getting the total number of elements in each row?

Comment: could you share example data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

result = df.select(sum((f.size(df[col_name]) for col_name in df.columns), f.lit(0)))
```

This solution uses the pyspark.sql built-in functions and will be executed in an optimized way. For more information about these functions, you can check its [pyspark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).

Comment: This looks very close to a good solution, thanks. The missing detail is the the arrays are not in columns, but are inside a structure (the unique column  `col` contains structures). I updated the question to make this very explicit, if this can help. What would be a clean way of accessing each field? There is always `df.col.getField(field_name)`, but if the fields could be iterated over directly without getting the field names first (which is cumbersome, as far as I know) that would be even better.

Comment: I would directly use the builtin `sum()` function, for summing the columns: `result = df.select(sum((f.size(df[col_name]) for col_name in df.columns), f.lit(0)))`. This uses the fact that the `sum()`'s second argument is the "zero" of the sum. (Except that, again, I don't have directly columns, but fields in a single column.)

Comment: @EOL Nice, I'ill update my answer with the sum function. Regarding the best solution, in pyspark I believe you have to use either getField as you said or the udf option (which is efficient enough, don't worry). In Scala, you could work with a strong-typed Dataset[Map[String, Array]] and use a simple map to get the result you want (something like `ds.map(_.flatMap(_._2).size)`).

Comment: @EOL In any case, I think the udf is a good option, considering the complex schema that I didn't see at first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment: I understand that the fields complicate things a bit too much compared to the user-defined function from the question. Side note: since you are now using a Pythonic sum, I took the liberty of removing your comment about your Python being rusty. :D

Comment: I am still hoping for someone to add an answer with a convenient equivalent of the column access but for fields. In the mean time, maybe you can edit your answer so as to add the case of fields, as asked in the question? This way I could eventually mark it as accepted. :)